# как удалить из массива объект по значению ключа Java script

Tags: javascript

Мне необходимо удалить из массива с объектами?  объект по значению ключа при нажатию на кнопку.

```
  var tasks = [ {id_task: "74", for_user_id: "160", time: null, date: "2018-9-13", task_name: "Решить вопрос с удалением задачи из массива при удалении"}, {id_task: "77", for_user_id: "160", time: null, date: "2018-9-10", task_name: "sss"}];

    button.onclick = function(){
        let del = this.parentNode.getAttribute('taskid');

            for(let i = 0; i <= tasks.length; i++){
                if(tasks[i].id_task == del){
                    delete tasks[i];    
                }
            }
    }
```

получаю ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id_task' of undefined
    at HTMLSpanElement.deleteTask (todo_list_block.js:53)

Comment: проблема в `<=` но вообще не стоит использовать delete с массивом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        for (let i = tasks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (tasks[i].id_task == del) {
                tasks.splice(i, 1);    
                break; // ?
            }
        }
```

Comment: благодарю, я в поисковике натыкался на splice но не мог правильно его применить в этом случае. =)